# Numpy Median Value Calculated not represented on BarPlot, How can I represent values according

Tags: python-3.x, seaborn

Hi and thank you for visiting my post.

**Here is working code that produces the median values**

```
Wall_Median = pd.pivot_table(cleaned_pokedex, values="Wall", index ='Primary Type',aggfunc={"Wall": np.median})                            
Final_Wall_Median = Wall_Median.nlargest(18,'Wall')
print(Final_Wall_Median)
```

**E.g Poison is 193 and the bar chart shows over 200**

> ```
> 1. Wall Primary Type        
> Steel         259.0
> Fairy         244.0
> Dragon        237.0
> Rock          235.5
> Ground        235.0
> Ice           230.0
> Flying        220.0
> Fighting      216.0
> Ghost         215.0
> Psychic       215.0
> Grass         209.5
> Water         208.0
> Fire          204.0
> Electric      201.0
> Dark          200.0
> Normal        194.0
> Poison        193.0
> Bug           180.0
> ```

**Plotting the values using a seaborn bar chart does not produce the numeric value I receive from the code**

```
fig = plt.gcf()
fig.set_size_inches(20,18)

ax = sns.barplot(x= cleaned_pokedex["Wall"],y= cleaned_pokedex["Primary Type"],data= Final_Wall_Median,palette = pkmn_type_colors)
```

**Output[image]**

The bar values don't represent the medians printed. What can I do to fix this ?

Comment: Please do not paste code as images.

Comment: Hi DYZ, Is this a moderation for my post or was this your input as it prevents you from answering this question above ?

Comment: It's in the FAQ: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Also important for this question: [How do I create a minimal complete verifiable example?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349789/how-do-i-create-a-minimal-complete-verifiable-example)

Comment: Thank you so much, I will edit and hopefully receive some feedback. The images I used to detail the discrepancy between the median value and the represent median.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`barplot()` takes a parameter `estimator=` that defines how the bar height is calculated. By default, this is done using `mean()`, but you can pass `median` if that's what you want:

`ax = sns.barplot(..., estimator=np.median)`

Comment: Thank you @diziet, I really do appreciate your explanation. I was under the impression that the variable `Wall_Median` stored the median due to `aggfunc={"Wall": np.median})`. I did not know that I would need to explicitly state the bars to plot the median.

Comment: You'll have to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that includes a toy dataset (refer to [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)). The fact that the plot shows errorbars around each bars suggest that there are several values for each categories in your dataframe, which are averaged together.

Comment: I would just like some more clarity on this. Are you inferencing that the plot that I displayed is showing an aggregated mean of the median values ? The error bars suggest that they are are multiple values for the median ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are actually plotting the mean with a CI band instead of the median as you intend to. That is because there is a small contradiction in your code:

```
ax = sns.barplot(x= cleaned_pokedex["Wall"],y= cleaned_pokedex["Primary Type"],data= Final_Wall_Median,palette = pkmn_type_colors)
```

1. you are telling `seaborn` to get the `x` and `y` values from `cleaned_pokedex` dataframe,
2. however, then you tell it to use `data` from the `Final_Wall_Median` dataframe.

So it seems that `seaborn` is arbitrarily choosing to use your `y~x` provided data, instead of the pre-aggregated `Final_Wall_Median` that you pass into `data`. Typically, you would use only `x` and `y` attributes if you just want to pass any two arrays (they don't need to be from the same dataframe), OR you can profile `data` as the dataframe you can't to use, and `x` and `y` as string column names (e.g. `(x="Wall", y="Primary Type", data=cleaned_pokedex)`)

However, as pointed out, if you simply pass the "Wall", "Primary Type" dimensions into the `x` and `y` values of a `barplot`, `seaborn` will by default use the "mean" as the estimator.

The two options you have are:

```py
sns.barplot(x=cleaned_pokedex["Wall"], y=cleaned_pokedex["Primary Type"], estimator=np.median)

# or

sns.barplot(x=Final_Wall_Median.Wall, y=Final_Wall_Median.index)
```

Since you've already pre-aggregated the medians, you can use `Final_Wall_Median` directly. The only difference is that you cannot get CI bands if you don't supply the raw data (the whole `cleaned_pokedex` dataframe, as in the first option).